# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority metrics-server

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, metrics-server

I am new to kubernetes and I finally realized how to launch the metrics-server as documented [kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server). In case that someone else wonders you need to deploy on Master node and also have minimum one worker in the cluster.

So I get this error:

```sh
E0818 15:25:22.835094       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:<hostname-master>: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet <hostname-master> (<hostname-master>): Get https://<hostname-master>:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:<hostname-worker>: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet <hostname-worker> (<hostname-worker>): Get https://<hostname-worker>:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority]
```

I am using my own CAs (not self signed) and I have modified the components.yml file (sample):

```sh
args:
  - --cert-dir=/tmp/metricsServerCas
  - --secure-port=4443
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=Hostname
```

I know that I can disable the tls by using this flag `--kubelet-insecure-tls` I have already tried it. I want to use my own CAs for extra security.

I have see other many relevant questions (few samples) e.g.:

[x509 certificate signed by unknown authority- Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939381/x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-kubernetes) and [kubectl unable to connect to server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234295/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-server-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authori)

Although that I have applied chown already my `$HOME/.kube/config` still I see this error.

Where am I going wrong?

**Update:** On the worker I am creating a directory e.g. `/tmp/ca` and I add the ca file(s) in the directory.

I am not really good yet with the mounting points and I assume that I am doing something wrong. The default syntax of the images can be found here [kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/v0.3.7](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/tag/v0.3.7) (see components.yml file).

I tried to create a directory on my worker e.g. /tmp/ca and I modified the flag `--cert-dir=/tmp/ca` and `mountPath: /tmp/ca`

When I am deploying the file e.g.:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.7/components.yaml
```

I keep getting the error from the metrics-server-xxxx:

```sh
panic: open /tmp/client-ca-file805316981: read-only file system
```

Although I have given full access to the directory e.g.:

```sh
$ ls -la /tmp/ca
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user   20 Aug 19 16:59 .
drwxrwxrwt. 18 root        root        4096 Aug 19 17:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 user user 1025 Aug 19 16:59 ca.crt
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

How is meant to be configured so someone can use non self signed certificates? I can see that most people are using non SSL which I would like to avoid.

Sample of my args in the image:

```sh
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  template:
    metadata:
      name: metrics-server
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      # mount in tmp so we can safely use from-scratch images and/or read-only containers
      - name: tmp-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.3.7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
          - --cert-dir=/tmp/ca
          - --secure-port=4443
          - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=Hostname
        ports:
        - name: main-port
          containerPort: 4443
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: /tmp/ca
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
        kubernetes.io/arch: "amd64"
```

**Update 2:** Adding curl command from Master to Worker including error output:

```sh
$ curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt https://node_hostname:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: When you deployed the kube cluster did you generate kubelet certs using your CA?

Comment: Yes I did produce my own certs based on the node name (hostname).

Comment: Check kubelet and metrics server logs..it would print some log messages which says generating self signed cert if its using self sighed cert. Also just curl that endpoint with your CA cert as parameter and see if that works

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu - I just tried to change the dirs in the components.yml file e.g. from `--cert-dir=/tmp/` to `--cert-dir=/tmp/sample`. I have created this dir on both Master and Worker, passed the certs, redeployed the image and still I get the error:

`panic: unable to load server certificate: open /tmp/sample: no such file or directory`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Thanos could you share the `Deployment` definition of your `metrics-server`? Could you tell how you are passing this certs to the `Deployment`?

Comment: @DawidKruk I just updated the question with more information and the error that I am getting now. Let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: @Thanos edit the question to add the modified section of the yaml

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Please see the updated text. Thank you again for your time and effort. Note that those files are placed on the worker.

Comment: @Thanos which Kubernetes version are you using? How this cluster was created (`kubeadm`, `minikube`, `kubespray`)? Have you checked and made sure that the requirements are met for the `metrics-server` described here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#requirements? Could you share what exactly have you done to deploy `metrics-server` step by step? Are your cluster created with certificates of your own `CA`?

Comment: The version that I used before was 1.18.2 and metrics server v0.3.6. Deployment was through kubeadm. Yes all requirements was exactly as the metrics-server/requirements. The good news is that I got it running by upgrading my k8s version on 1.19.0 and using the latest version v0.3.7. It works with self signed certificates. :)

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved your issue :). Please provide your comment as an answer with an explanation of how you've managed to resolve your issue and also for better visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give better visibility as the solution was posted in the comments.

> The version that I used before was 1.18.2 and metrics server v0.3.6. Deployment was through kubeadm. Yes all requirements was exactly as the metrics-server/requirements. The good news is that I got it running by upgrading my k8s version on 1.19.0 and using the latest version v0.3.7. It works with self signed certificates.

The issue was resolved by upgrading:

- `Kubernetes`: `1.18.2` -> `1.19.0`
- `Metrics-server`: `0.3.6` -> `0.3.7`

This upgrade allowed to run `metrics-server` with `tls` enabled (self-signed certificates).

---

Additional resources that could help when deploying `metrics-server` with `tls`:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes-sigs: Metrics-server: FAQ: How to run metrics-server-securely](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-run-metrics-server-securely)*

> How to run metrics-server securely?
> Suggested configuration:
>
> - Cluster with [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) enabled
> - Kubelet [read-only port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options) port disabled
> - Validate kubelet certificate by mounting CA file and providing --kubelet-certificate-authority flag to metrics server
> - Avoid passing insecure flags to metrics server (--deprecated-kubelet-completely-insecure, --kubelet-insecure-tls)
> - Consider using your own certificates (--tls-cert-file, --tls-private-key-file)

- *[Github.com: Metrics-server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/146)*
- *[Ftclausen.github.io: Setting up K8S with metrics-server](https://ftclausen.github.io/general/setting_up_k8s_with_metrics_server/)*

Comment: Minor note. The proposed solution for me worked only with the latest calico network element on barebone. Any other element that I tried I got errors and restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Create a configmap to store the ca certificate which was used to generate kubelet serving certificate.

```
kubectl -n kube-system create configmap ca --from-file=ca.crt=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -o yaml
```

Then use volumeMounts to use it in metrics server pod

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: tmp-dir
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: ca
    name: ca-dir
  containers:
    args:
      - --cert-dir=/tmp
      - --secure-port=4443
      - --kubelet-certificate-authority=/ca/ca.crt
      - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=Hostname
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp
      name: tmp-dir
    - mountPath: /ca
      name: ca-dir
```

You can follow the same approach and use `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` for using your own certificate instead of self signed certificate.

Comment: Is it by accident the names reverted or is suppose to be like this? e.g. `- mountPath: /tmp name: tmp-dir` instead of `- name: tmp-dir mountPath: /tmp`?

Comment: I tried it and it does not work for me :(. Also I reverted `- configMap:  defaultMode: 420 name: ca name: ca-dir` to `- name: ca-dir defaultMode: 420 name: ca configMap:`. Hmmm maybe this is the reason it did not worked. Your command above binds the name as ca of configMap. I will revert this and try again :)

Comment: Can you curl that same endpoint from node VMs using the same ca cert?

Answer (score 0):

For my friends on EKS make sure you have the username set (and not set to just the session name like I did):

```
robert ❱ kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system aws-auth -o yaml | grep MyTeamRole$ -A 3
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123546789012:role/MyTeamRole
  username: {{SessionName}}
  groups:
    - system:masters
robert ❱ kubectl top node
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
robert ❱ 1 ❱ kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system aws-auth
configmap/aws-auth edited
robert ❱ kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system aws-auth -o yaml | grep MyTeamRole$ -A 3
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123546789012:role/MyTeamRole
      username: literally_anything:{{SessionName}}
      groups:
        - system:masters
robert ❱ kubectl top node
NAME                                       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
ip-10-0-3-103.us-west-2.compute.internal   341m         17%    1738Mi          52%
...
robert ❱ kubectl logs -n kube-system -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=metrics-server
E0407 22:34:45.879156       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:49.399854       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:50.691133       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:51.827629       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:07.288163       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:08.755492       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:09.801957       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:40:32.405458       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:43:09.791769       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:44:14.244221       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
robert ❱
```